# Python OO, self calling other functions inside class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am new to object oriented concepts, and I've tried solving this problem using OO technique. I have solved it using normal programming technique, but I cant get it to work with OO technique.

here is the problem: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-nested-logic?utm_campaign=30_days_of_code_continuous&utm_medium=email&utm_source=daily_reminder

What I've tried:
At first, I only called student1.print(). that didnt work so I called parseDate() and calculateFine().
I put self in all the variables in my student class as I fail to truly understand why or how self works.

Apologizes if I incorrectly labeled the title, but I didnt know what else to write, as I am not certain what exactly is the problem in my code.

```
class getFine():
    def __init__ (self,expectedDate,actualDate):
        self.expectedDate = expectedDate
        self.actualDate = actualDate


    def parseDates(self):
        self.ya = self.actualDate[0]
        self.ma = self.actualDate[1]
        self.da = self.actualDate[0]

        self.ye = self.expectedDate[0]
        self.me = self.expectedDate[1]
        self.de = self.expectedDate[2]

    def calculateFine(self):
        self.fine = 0
        if(self.ya>self.ye):
            self.fine = 10000
        elif self.ya==self.ye:
            if(self.ma>self.me):
                self.fine = 500 * (self.ma-self.me)
            elif(self.ma==self.me) and (self.da>self.de):
                self.fine = 15 * (self.da-self.de)


    def print(self):
        print(self.fine)


def main():
    expectedDate = str(input().split(" "))
    actualDate = str(input().split(" "))
    student1 = getFine(expectedDate, actualDate)
    student1.parseDates()
    student1.calculateFine()
    student1.print()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are strings, which you then want to subtract from each other. First convert them to integers or floats using something like this:

```
expectedDate = [int(i) for i in (input().split(" "))]
actualDate = [int(i) for i in (input().split(" "))]
```

Does this solve your problem?

---

If you want to only call the `getFine.print()` function and not the other funtions, you could call these class methods in the `getFine.print()` method. Since you probably want to separate the year month and date on every function call, you could move that part to the init method

```
class getFine():
    def __init__ (self,expectedDate,actualDate):
        self.expectedDate = expectedDate
        self.actualDate = actualDate

        self.ya = self.actualDate[0]
        self.ma = self.actualDate[1]
        self.da = self.actualDate[2]    # typo here 0 --> 2

        self.ye = self.expectedDate[0]
        self.me = self.expectedDate[1]
        self.de = self.expectedDate[2]


    def calculateFine(self):
        self.fine = 0
        if(self.ya>self.ye):
            self.fine = 10000
        elif self.ya==self.ye:
            if(self.ma>self.me):
                self.fine = 500 * (self.ma-self.me)
            elif(self.ma==self.me) and (self.da>self.de):
                self.fine = 15 * (self.da-self.de)


    def print(self):
        self.calculateFine()
        print(self.fine)


expectedDate = [int(i) for i in (input().split(" "))]
actualDate = [int(i) for i in (input().split(" "))]
student1 = getFine(expectedDate, actualDate)
student1.print()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time and help, it worked and I learnt something new after hours of head scratching :)